# Django: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: django, python-3.x

I used to check every answer to this question< but NOTHING helped me.
Here's a error:

```
edjango.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

In settings file is:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'
```

and WSGI file is:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyLittleTest.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Can you help me with this issue plz?

Comment: You need to show the full traceback of that error.

Comment: Show us the `project structure`

Answer (score -1):

I think you need:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mylittletest.wsgi.application'
```

or how your project is called.

Comment: I changed to: WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MyLittleTest.wsgi.application'

Comment: Which wsgi server do you use for deployment? (gunicorn, apache wsgi mod or something else). EDIT: and you may try mylittletest.wsgi.application in lower case.

Comment: I use only startserver, it's the first time I start to run something in django

Comment: the lower case doesn't help me